# How to use fnamemodify to return dirname/filename?

Tags: vimscript

I am using vim-airline and buffer tabline. I want to make the tab name become `dirname/filename`. How to achieve it?

For example

`:ec fnamemodify('/usr/lib/abc/file.sh', '<something>')` should return `abc/file.sh`.

I tried many combinations `:p:.`, `:t`, `:r`, `:h` etc.. None of them works.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would simply use `matchstr()` or `substitute()` in that case

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is from @osse at IRC.

```
let name = '/usr/lib/abc/file.sh'
fnamemodify(name, ':p:h:t') . '/' . fnamemodify(name, ':t')
```

See help docs that I found interesting:

- `:help filename-modifiers`
- `:help fnamemodify`
- `:help getcwd`
- `:help globpath`
- `:help split`
- `:help substitute`
- `:help wildcards`

Comment: It would be worth mentioning [`:h filename-modifiers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers) in the answer so that future readers know how the modifiers you used work and how to get more information on them later.